# Paypal payment processing

Tags: c#, winforms, soap, paypal

I've checked out the resources on PayPal's site, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup recurring payments from a "create account" form I've created in C#.

My goals is to have a text field called "username" that's disabled and enables when the user processes their payment through Paypal by clicking on a link that opens the payment page in their browser. I want to then save some kind of ID associated with that transaction that my application can look up when the user logs in to make sure they still have an active subscription.

All that being said, I have two questions. One, is there a good walk though for someone who doesn't know much about SOAP or anything of the sort? Possibly geared toward Paypal? Second, does Paypal give some kind of static transaction ID that I can look up via Paypal when the user logs in?

I'm also open to other payment processing methods, but I want to stick with WinForms for a while.

Comment: all the info u need could be found through a simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/createrecurringpaymentsprofile-api-operation-nvp) to create the subscription with PayPal.  If you don't like working with SOAP you can use their basic NVP API, which is what that link points to.

When you make that call to create the profile you'll get back a PROFILEID.  This profile ID can be passed into [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails-api-operation-nvp) to check the current status upon login.

Since you're using C# I'd recommend taking a look at this [.NET SDK for PayPal](http://www.encoresystems.net/PayPalSdk.aspx).  It makes the calls very simple for you.

Comment: I don't mind learning SOAP or NVP, just when I look at the "first call" thing, I'm very confused on how that goes into C#. Do I just need to research SOAP/NVP and massage the information on their site into C#?

Comment: .NET / C# has specific ways to do this to make it easy, but you're basically just building a string of text, whether it's XML or NVP, and then sending that to PayPal via POST.  That .NET SDK I linked you to handles this for you, actually.  I'd recommend taking a look at it.

Comment: Awesome. Sorry for the newb questions, but I think after reading it a few things and sleeping on it, it makes sense -- my brain digests things in a weird way. So, for PayPal, it sounds like I'll send the POST command to PayPal and I'll get a URL to send the users to after. Does that come from the return?

Comment: If you're using Express Checkout, yes.  The SetExpressCheckout request will return a token that you append to the end of the URL that you redirect the user to at PayPal. The documentation covers this in detail.